I want to return to New Zealand
I left New Zealand in 1986.
I have been living in South Africa for 34years.
I'm now 60!
I want to return to New Zealand but don't know how to start the process!
I'm looking to bring my belongings - household, vehicle, 2 cats, 1 dog & a pig, possibly 5 sheep (a part of a stud flock I have had for 30yrs).
Is there someone out there that advise me on returning "home"?

Are you a New Zealand citizen ?

Yes, born & bred!
